# I'm trying to set my JAVA_HOME path to use my javac.exe?

Tags: java, android, variables, command-line, cordova

I'm on Windows 7 and I'm trying to set my `JAVA_HOME` path to use PhoneGap on android, when i create a project using the command line "cmd" it tells me that it can't find javac.exe? although i'm sure that I've set the variable right

here's my stuff:

```
Variable name: JAVA_HOME
Variable value: C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin
(I've also tried to use: C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\javac.exe)
```

My javac.exe location on my laptop `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\javac.exe`

and it still tells me that it can't locate the `javac.exe`

What I type to create the project and i meet this problem is this:

```
C:\Users\user>cd C:\Users\user\Desktop\phonegap-2.8.1\lib\android\bin

C:\Users\user\Desktop\phonegap-2.8.1\lib\android\bin>create.bat
Cannot locate javac.exe using the PATH environment variable.
Retry after adding directory containing javac.exe to the PATH variable.
Remember to open a new command window after updating the PATH variable.
Visit http://java.oracle.com if you need to install Java (JDK).
```

Also, i've tries restarting the windows and closing the command prompt and redownloading the JDK.

Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

`cmd` is using the values from the `PATH` variable to locate `javac` :

```
set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin"
```

For other softwares (Tomcat, Maven, etc.) `JAVA_HOME` must indicate the root of your JDK :

```
set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\"
```

No need to restart Windows. When using `set` the changes are taken immediately.

If you choose to modify those variables in the Control Panel, you have to close and relaunch `cmd` for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add java

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin
```

Note that your path may be different.

to your environment variables and restart your console.

You can find how to set your variables here:
http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html

Comment: Shall I restart the windows? I tried and it still can't locate it

Comment: Are you 100% certain that you have the JDK installed and not the JRE? JDK = Java Development Kit and JRE = Java Runtime Environment. The JRE doesn't have a java compiler (javac.exe). You should download the JDK from the website again, install it in a different folder and check if javac.exe is in that /bin folder. Then point your environment variable to that folder.

Comment: cmd uses PATH variable to locate javac. In my case, "java" command was working but javac was not. So I had to add java path in both "Path" and "JAVA_HOME" environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Set the JAVA_HOME Variable

```
Right-click the My Computer icon on your desktop and select Properties.
Click the Advanced system settings. Click the
Environment Variables button. Under System Variables, click New.
Enter the variable name as JAVA_HOME.
Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17).
Click OK.
Click Apply Changes.
```

You might need to restart windows.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `JAVA_HOME` environmental variable to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17
```

Press

```
Win + Break > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > System Variables
```

Modify/set `JAVA_HOME` to the above. (No need to restart)

Comment: shall i restart the windows? i tries and it still can't locate it.

Comment: @JosephSafwat. In PATH environment variable, add an entry - `%JAVA_HOME%\bin'. No need to restart windows.

Answer (score 0):

I already had this error when I tried to create a new phonegap project for android but unfortunately I don't remember how exactly I have fixed this.

I don't know if you have followed the phonegap documentation so here is the link : [new project](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android), especially the part 3B (be careful about `;` in your `PATH`).
If you don't know what to do now, maybe you should do it again step by step.

Answer (score 0):

May be a little old, but since this is the first goolge result, I might as well add a little something.

You need to create the JAVA_HOME variable AND edit the PATH variable, adding `;%JAVA_HOME%\bin` (with a ;) so cmd and some other apps can actually use javac and the rest of the tools